# Как найти виджет(-ы), лежащие на QGridLayout

Tags: c++, qt

Вопрос в заголовке. Пытался сделать так

```
QGridLayout *layout;
...
QPushButton *btn = new QPushButton("click me");
QPlainTextEdit *textEdit = new QPlainTextEdit();
layout->addWidget(textEdit);
layout->addWidget(btn);

QPlainTextEdit *foundTextEdit = layout->findChild<QPlainTextEdit*>();
if (!foundTextEdit)
    qDebug() << "((("; //всегда срабатывает
qDebug() << layout->children().size(); //всегда выводит 0
```

но ничего не вышло.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел на английской версии сайта как перебирать: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065378/qt-get-children-from-layout. Удалял с помощью `QLayout::takeItem` и `delete`.
Пример:

```
QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout;
QPushButton *btn = new QPushButton("click me!");
QPlainTextEdit *textEdit = new QPlainTextEdit;

layout->addWidget(btn);
layout->addWidget(textEdit);

for (int i = 0; i < layout->count(); ++i)
{
    QWidget *widget = layout->itemAt(i)->widget();
    //qobject_cast<QPushButton*>(widget) или qobject_cast<QPlainTextEdit*>(widget)
}

while (QLayoutItem *itm = layout->takeItem(0))
{
    delete itm->widget();
    delete itm;
}
```

Comment: Только лучше все же не `delete itm->widget();` a `itm->widget()->deleteLater();`